# Curry’s paradox in Turing machine land?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, paradoxes

### Background

There’s an [excellent question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427842/will-this-turing-machine-find-a-proof-of-its-halting) that talks about the following: imagine that $M$ is a TM that searches over all ZFC proofs and halts if and only if it finds a proof that it halts. The answer is yes because it’s possible to adapt the logic behind [Löb’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) to Turing machines.

At that question is a [remarkable answer by Akiva Weinberger](https://mathoverflow.net/a/427848) that spells out an explicit argument, based on the proof of Löb’s theorem, showing why this machine $M$ halts:

> Build a second machine $N$. $N$ searches for a proof in ZFC of, "if $N$ halts then $M$ halts". If it finds
> one, it halts.
>
> ZFC can argue as follows. "Suppose $N$ halts. Then it found a proof that if $N$ halts then $M$ halts. This, combined with the trace of $N$ halting, would be a ZFC proof that $M$ halts. Thus $M$ finds this and halts."
>
> That paragraph is a ZFC proof that if $N$ halts then $M$ halts… which $N$ finds, so $N$ halts. Thus, by the same logic as above, there is a proof that $M$ halts, which it will find and then halt on.

Löb’s theorem is closely related to [Curry’s paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox). Briefly, Curry’s paradox envisions a statement $P$ that says “if $P$ is true, then $\phi$ is true,” where $\phi$ is some arbitrary statement. The paradox is that this seems to imply that $\phi$ is true regardless of what $\phi$ is.

### My Question

Pick any statement $\phi$. I’m going to argue that ZFC proves $\phi$. (Clearly it doesn’t, so there has to be a flaw in the following reasoning. However, I’m not sure what it is!) This is essentially a minimally-modified version of Akiva Weinberger’s MO answer but applied to Curry’s paradox rather than Löb’s theorem. To make it easier to see the changes, I’ve bolded all parts that differ from the original.

Consider a TM $M$ that searches over all ZFC proofs and halts if and only if it finds a proof of the statement “**if $M$ halts, then $\phi$ is true.**”

Build a second machine $N$. $N$ searches for a proof in ZFC of, "if $N$ halts, then **if $M$ halts, then $\phi$ is true.**” If it finds one, it halts.

ZFC can argue as follows. "Suppose $N$ halts. Then it found a proof that if $N$ halts, then **if $M$ halts, then $\phi$ is true**. This, combined with the trace of $N$ halting, would be a ZFC proof that **if $M$ halts, then $\phi$ is true**. Thus $M$ finds this and halts. **This, combined with a trace of $M$ halting, would be a ZFC proof of $\phi$.**

That paragraph is a ZFC proof that if $N$ halts, then **if $M$ halts, then $\phi$ is true**… which $N$ finds, so $N$ halts. Thus, by the same logic as above, there is a proof that $M$ halts, which it will find and then halt on. **And since $M$ halts, a trace of $M$ halting, plus the preceding argument, gives a ZFC proof of $\phi$**.

There has to be something wrong with the above argument, but I confess I’m not seeing what it is. Can someone point out where I’m telling lies? :-)

Comment: How can a Turing machine contain a description of itself in its state machine to decide if some string is a halting run of itself?  The machine is not complete until you encode the string describing it into its state machine.

Comment: This is possible due to [Kleene’s second recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem). It’s analogous to the idea of a program that prints its own source code (a Quine), which is possible despite the fact that it seems like the program wouldn’t be “complete” without containing a copy of its source code. (See Chapter 6 of Sipser’s _Introduction to the Theory of Computation_ for a good explanation.)

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.  The reference talks about taking a complete $M$ and creating another machine $N$ that has $M$ embedded in it.  You're talking about a machine that has itself embedded in it.  Just because there are some programs that print their own code doesn't mean all programs can be embedded in themselves.  They can be embedded in another program.

Comment: The second recursion theorem I linked in my comment states, essentially, that TMs can compute arbitrary functions of their own encodings. See [these lecture slides](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1242/lectures/22/) for more details and an concrete example of a program that computes a nontrivial property of itself.

Comment: Does a Turing machine $M$ that does nothing - just halts on its starting step satisfy the definition of $M$ in the first paragraph?  If $M$ is a fixed point for something, what is it a fixed point for?  Can you write the program $M$ in any programming language of your choice?  If $M$ is a fixed point, can you write the program $N$ that $M$ is a fixed point for in any programming language?  What does the program take as input?  What do you mean by 'halts'?  A specific input or all inputs?  If you mean all inputs, what's a proof in ZFC that a program halts on all inputs?  Is that computable?

Comment: An always-halting TM would not meet the requirements because were specifically interested in a TM that loops over all proofs and checks for a proof that it itself halts. You could imagine writing a TM $X$ that takes in a TM $Y$ as input, searches for a proof that $Y$ halts, then halts if and only if it finds one. Applying Kleene’s theorem to that TM then produces $M$. This could be done in any Turing-complete language. As for which inputs - let’s relax our model of TMs a bit and imagine that, like Turing’s original conception, a TM starts with a blank tape and runs from there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a contradiction anywhere.  Let $\varphi$ be a statement in the language of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  Let $\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner$ be a string encoding $\varphi$.  Let $\text{prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ be the formula that says there exists a string encoding a proof of $\varphi$ from the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

For a Turing machine $M$ and a string $\ulcorner M\urcorner$ encoding $M$, let $\text{halt}(\ulcorner M\urcorner)$ be the formula that says there exists a string encoding a run of $M$ halting on the empty input.

What you showed is that there is a Turing machine $M_\varphi$, encoded by a string $\ulcorner M_\varphi\urcorner$ such that
$$\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\text{halt}(\ulcorner M_\varphi\urcorner)\rightarrow\text{prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$$

and also that there is a Turing machine $N_\varphi$ encoded by $\ulcorner N_\varphi\urcorner$ such that
$$\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\text{halt}(\ulcorner N_\varphi\urcorner)\land\text{halt}(\ulcorner M_\varphi\urcorner))\rightarrow\text{prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$$

but unless $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\text{halt}(\ulcorner N_\varphi\urcorner)\land\text{halt}(\ulcorner M_\varphi\urcorner))$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\text{halt}(\ulcorner M_\varphi\urcorner)$ you cannot conclude from this that $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\text{prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$.

It's difficult to understand why you need either $M$ or $N$.  You can build a
machine $M$ that searches the space of strings for proofs of $\varphi$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ directly.  Why do you need a machine $M$ to search for proofs that 'If $M$ halts on the empty input then $\varphi$ is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$'?  A machine that searches for proofs of $\varphi$ will halt on the empty input if and only if $\varphi$ is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I’d get a better sense for why my argument doesn’t work if I could see the original (correct) argument about Löb’s theorem recast using your notation. Would it be possible to see why the original argument is correct but why my modified one fails?

Comment: @templatetypedef:  Your argument doesn't fail.  You proved that the provability predicate of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is reducible to the halting problem.  That's not a contradiction in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  It's long known and doesn't need any fixed point theorems.  There's a direct reduction from $\text{prov}$ to $\text{halt}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

> That paragraph is a ZFC proof that if N halts, then if M
> halts, then ϕ is true

The relevant paragraph only talks about proofs of $\phi,$ not $\phi$ itself. So all you can say at that point is:

> That paragraph is a ZFC proof that if N halts, then if M
> halts, then ZFC proves ϕ

which isn't as useful.

---

A good way to find the mistake is to take $\phi=\bot$ (i.e. any contradiction). Then using the 2nd incompleteness theorem it's easy to see that these are equivalent in a weak metatheory:

- $M$ halts
- $N$ halts
- ZFC is inconsistent

In particular we (and ZFC) can prove "if $M$ and $N$ halt then $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \phi$". But ZFC cannot prove "if $M$ and $N$ halt then $\phi$", unless it's inconsistent.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. So to clarify, the issue is that the relevant bit is a ZFC proof of “if N halts, then if M halts, then ZFC proves phi” rather than “if N halts, then if M halts, then phi,” so in the next paragraph where we talk about N finding the proof, it doesn’t necessarily find a proof of the statement it’s searching for? And that differs from the original (correct) proof because… help me finish that sentence?